# Creating library for Phaser.io with WebPack - Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, phaser-framework

I am trying to write a small FOSS UI component library for the Phaser.io game engine. The code lives [here](https://github.com/JTronLabs/phaser-ui). In the `src/` dir I have a bunch of components that are exported in the `index.js` file. These components are bundled using the `webpack.config.js` and exported to `build/phaser-ui.js`.

I am having trouble using my built file. Inside the `test/` directory, I have created a Phaser Game for testing with the [phaser-plus](https://github.com/rblopes/generator-phaser-plus) Yeoman generator. My `phaser-ui` package is installed in the test's package.json from a relative link. This seems to work fine.

The issue I am having is that it appears my `phaser-ui` file does not have  access to the Phaser Library. In the test game I am trying to import a component from the phaser-ui package.json dependency, but this causes the following error to be thrown.

Inside the Game.js state:

`import ProgressBar from "phaser-ui";`

[image: stack trace error]
[image]

HTML5 Game Dev Forums post [here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/28476-issues-when-creating-a-small-foss-phaserio-ui-library/)
Source repo [here](https://github.com/JTronLabs/phaser-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K so I got it halfway working (**update** - works 100%). I changed my test script to properly reinstall the package in the test dir each time:

PHASER-UI's package.json

```
"scripts": {
 "test": "npm run build && cd test && npm install phaser-ui && npm start",
 "build": "webpack"
},
```

The test package installs phaser-ui from a local NPM directory

TEST's package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "phaser-ce": "^2.7.0",
    "phaser-ui": "file:../"
  },
```

Then, I included the 'Phaser' variable as an external in my webpack

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: 'build/',
        filename: 'phaser-ui.js'
    },
    //needed in my src library when extending/using Phaser objects/code
    externals: {
        Phaser: 'Phaser'
    }
};
```

So now it builds successfully and seems to work. The issue is that I don't know how to consume it in my game state. Importing and logging it only shows a generic object in the console

```
import * as lib from 'phaser-ui';

export default class Game extends Phaser.State {

  create() {
    console.log(lib)
  }

}
```

[image: phaser-ui import]

### Update

Turns out I needed to add some library configuration to my webpack.config.js. By default [webpack libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) are designed to be "installed" via a `scripts` tag and consumed via a global variable. I want my library to be a node_module that is consumed by an `import componentName from 'phaser-ui';`, so I needed to change the [libraryTarget](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget) to `umd`.

Final `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    //setup the webpack output as a library
    output: {
        path: 'build/',
        filename: 'phaser-ui.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd', //Honestly not sure of diffs between umd, amd, commonjs, etc (but umd works!)
        library: 'phaserUi'
    },        
    //needed in my src library when extending/using Phaser objects/code
    externals: {
        Phaser: 'Phaser'
    }
};
```

Comment: yes. my current phaser ts setup also looks like this. And the code do not need to import phaser

Answer (score 1):

In you code, you have, from line 1:

```
/*
 * Star
 * ====
 *
 * Individual star paritcles in the background star emitters
 */

export default class Star extends Phaser.Particle {
// ...
```

Looks like you haven't imported the library. `Phaser` is undefined, and so `Phaser.Particle` is undefined.

Did you forget to `const Phaser = require('phaser');` before using `Phaser`?

Alternatively, you can do `import {default as Phaser} from 'phaser';` If you want new syntax, and has set up environment to use it.

Comment: Thank you for looking it over! Just did this and pushed it to GitHub, but am experiencing the same error. Also the consumer of the library should  include Phaser, so if I include it in my bundle it will be in the final game output twice. I don't know why these individual imports aren't working though.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with WebPack externals, though I have not hit upon a winning configuration yet - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: I discovered the reason including all of Phaser didn't work. It seems my test project was using an old version of the `phaser-ui` library - my scripts for using a local project are not configured correctly, fixing that now.